# Is a p-value of 0.05 always enough when it comes to statistical significance when doing research?

Tags: statistics, data-analysis, p-value

I often see that a p-value of 0.05 is used in order to determine statistical significance. Why is it 0.05 and is this value always used in research? Are there cases where a p-value of 0.05 is not appropriate and why?

Comment: See: https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/observations/five-sigmawhats-that/#:~:text=Scientists%20use%20p%2Dvalues%20to%20test%20the%20likelihood%20of%20hypotheses.&text=High%2Denergy%20physics%20requires%20even,discovery%22%20is%20p%3D0.0000003..

Comment: @ElchananSolomon That looks like an answer to me. I had heard particle physics had much stricter requirements, but had no idea of the magnitude.

Comment: Obligatory: https://xkcd.com/882/

Comment: Originally it was an $\alpha$ value of $0.05$ based on R.A. Fisher's practical experience experimenting at  Rothamsted that results more than two standard deviations from the expected value were often worth investigating further. The value of it as common usage is that people who have seen it sometimes  produce false positive results in their own work  (Type 1 errors) will understand that it can do the same in others'.